# Retrieve keycloak group id for a specific group

Tags: rest, api, keycloak

I am trying to access a group id of a specific group from keycloak. What I found is like there is no REST Api call is available for access this one. You can refer here http://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/3.0/rest-api/index.html#_groups_resource. This shows that you can access all group details or specific group details only by using their Id's. Actually what I actually need is I want to access only the id of the specific group. Can anyone let me know how to do this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Where can we find the id of the group?

Answer (score 9):

You can write it like this:

```
GET  http://localhost:your_port/auth/admin/realms/your_realm_name/groups?search=name_of_the_group
```

it will return {**id, name, path, subGroups**} to you..

[My Postman Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjyJT.png)

Comment: if you add briefRepresentation=flase as a query parameter, you also receive the realmRoles, attributes and clientRoles

Comment: why the subgroups are empty. Without search string it give all the subgroups related to groups. but when use "search=group_name" it only give empty subgroup array. do you know any solution for this?

Comment: @KavishkaMadhushan there was an [update to the interface in version 23.0.0](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/25053#issuecomment-1888535340). Now subgroups have to be fetched using "GET /groups/{group id}/children", for each group where `subGroupCount` is not 0.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation you're using is pretty old. Take a look at the documentation for the latest release:

https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/4.8/rest-api/#_groups_resource

You can provide a "search" parameter to look for groups by name.

Unfortunately, if you use the name of a subGroup, it returns the entire hierarchy starting from the top-level group, so the API for groups is still problematic.

Answer (score 4):

This might come a bit late, but anyway.

There is also the `GET /{realm}/group-by-path/{path}` endpoint which will return only the group that you desire since `path` is unique.

Also if someone needs (and since this isn't actually documented, or at least not as of the writing of this answer) if you want to call this endpoint from the admin-cli you can do it as follows:
`./kcadm.sh get group-by-path/{path} --realm {realm}`

`ex.: ./kcadm.sh get group-by-path/parent_group/child_group/grand_child_group --realm realm1`

Answer (score 2):

One way is to enter keycloak admin panel. Then in the Groups option, select a group. Finally you will find the group id in the URL. Like */realms/Applications/groups/**bc49dc6c-7c2a-40c4-bf60-fea8c2b1d562***

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all groups:

`GET /admin/realms/{realm}/groups`

The response will have group properties including id.

```
[
  {
    "id": "8ge163b3-6kc7-40ed-x069-3309eabbcbea",
    "name": "group1",
    "path": "/group1",
    "subGroups": []
  }
]
```